# React.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED when uploading file with fetch API

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, file-upload, upload, fetch-api

##### Context

I have a Spring Boot application for backend, and I use React.js for frontend.
I want to upload images from the UI and process it on the backend.

This is the js code for the file upload:

```
export async function uploadImage(authHeader, id, image) {
    const url = new URL(`${WEBSTORE_API_URL}/products/${id}/image`);
    const requestOptions = {
        mode: 'cors',
        method: 'PUT',
        body: image,
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': authHeader,
            //'Content-Type': image.type,
            //'Content-Length': image.length,
        },
    };
    return await fetch(url, requestOptions);
}
```

##### The issue

When calling fetch(...), the following error is thrown:

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at uploadImage (uploadImage.js?t=1697580380505:26:26)
    at onSubmit (ProductImagesModal.jsx:60:15)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:3945:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:31)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070:25)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243:3)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275:7)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288:5)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299:3)
```

Weird thing is, this error is only thrown on this endpoint, when uploading a file above the size of ~7MB and the validation logic on the backend considers it as invalid (so basically there is no error thrown if the response is 200).

My React application doesn't seem to receive the response, even though the request is processed on the backend, and response with the status 400 is sent back.

##### CORS

I have read a couple of questions here regarding this error and it's mostly associated with a wrong CORS configuration, but I don't think that's the issue, because all other endpoints are working just fine (could be wrong).

##### Backend issue?

As I mentioned, I validate the incoming file on the backend. I receive it as an InputStream, wrap it in a BufferedInputStream, mark() it, perform the validation, and then reset(). This works well when the uploaded file is valid (even if it's a large file), but could it cause issues like this?

##### Method of uploading file

I did some research on how to do file upload in js (not very experienced), and I saw that using formData as body is preferable. I really want to receive the file as a stream though, and not sure if this is the right way to do it.

##### What I tried

- playing around with CORS but to no avail.
- switching to axios, which resulted in a slightly different error, but it also said Connection Aborted.
- many more backend related things

##### EDIT

I can get a response from Postman consistently.

Comment: I managed to fix this using 'server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=-1' in application.properties, in case anyone comes across this